# How to pass class fields from main class to Spring controller in a separate class?

Tags: java, spring

I'm developing a server using Spring Boot. I want to have a static UUID field in my main class using `java.util.UUID`. I want all controllers (implemented as standalone classes) to get a new uuid using the static field from main. But how do I pass a field from main to a controller in Spring Boot? Is there some kind of an annotation to do this?

This is my main class:

```
package com.vastserver;

import java.util.UUID;
import com.vastserver.db.DBHandler;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ServerMain implements CommandLineRunner {
    private static final UUID uuids = new UUID(1233, 45454);
    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(ServerMain.class);

    @Autowired
    private DBHandler db;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        log.warn("from main");
        SpringApplication.run(ServerMain.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
        log.info("starting run");
        db.initDBTables();
    }
}
```

Comment: Make the UUID a bean and autowire it, or make the field public.

Answer (score 0):

Following @Michael's comment I created a Spring bean:

```
package com.vastserver;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import java.util.UUID;

@Service
public class RandomUUID {
    private String uuid;

    public String getUuid() {
        return UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }

    public void setUuid(String uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }
}
```

and I added `@Autowired` field in my main class:

```
@Autowired
private RandomUUID uuid;
```

Additionally, I learned that it's not required per se to generate UUID's in a special class so as to guarantee their uniqueness. This is because according to UUID standard it's derived from [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) hence it'll be unique if called from multiple classes.